# Hyperledger Fabric change go path

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

My go path currently points to /usr/local/go but this IS NOT where I prefer to install projects.

What is the preferred method to point to the go path to *execute* go but build projects from a completely different directory? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you investigated so far? Please also refer the [ask] link.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Fabric?   This seems like a golang question.  A quick Google search will lead you to https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH

Comment: Many thanks -- we are making the very uncomfortable transition from HL Composer to full native Fabric - your response is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In fabric, you will install the chaincode from inside the cli container, that way don't matter specifically where your gopath is mapped on your machine.

Map your chaincode path to the container go_path:

```
volumes:
    - ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
```

And then install and instantiate it.